# Confusion with closure of sets

Tags: general-topology

In one of the solutions to the problem of open sets gives this line,

$\overline{X-U} \cap U \subset \overline{(X-U)\cap U}=\emptyset$

$\implies \overline{X-U} \subset X-U$

$\implies X-U \space\text{is closed}$

My question is why is $X-U$ closed? (Note the overline here indicates the closure of the overlined set).

**EDIT: Second Question:**

If $A$ is a dense subset of $X$ and $U $ is open, then $A\cap U$ is dense in $U$. So in the solution it says, $x\in U \implies x\in X=\overline{A}$, my question is, why is $x \in U$ also, why does $x \in U$ imply that $x \in X?$

Comment: On your second question: I suspect that $X$ denotes the whole space here and $A$ and $U$ are *subsets* of $X$.

Comment: Yes I got it now thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closure is the smallest closed set which contains $X-U$, so if $\overline{X-U} \subset X-U$, then $\overline{X-U} = X-U$ which means that $X-U$ is closed

Comment: ok this makes alot more sense than what I was thinking. Thank you.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis I'm glad I could help.

Comment: I edited my post and asked a second question to avoid continuous new posts with small questions. Could you help me? Thank You.

Comment: The solution supposes $x\in U$ to reach a conclusion later. Then, does the exercise say if $U \subset X$? If so, then of course $x\in U \subset X \implies x \in X$.

Comment: I would have asked the second question in a separate post, because as this one has already been marked as solved, then the additional question wouldn't reach as much people to help with your doubt. @AuroraBorealis

Comment: Ooo ok so it seems like yes it clear now the confusion. Thanks alot !

Answer (score 2):

For $\overline{A}\subseteq A$, then $A$ is closed. One can prove that $A^{c}$ is open: For $a\in A^{c}$, since $a\notin\overline{A}$, there exists some open set $G$ that containing $a$ but $G\cap A=\emptyset$, so $a\in G\subseteq A^{c}$, we are done.

Definition of closure: $a\in\overline{A}$ if for every open set $G$ that containing $a$, then $G\cap A\ne\emptyset$.